# How to draw rectangle and ellipse on JFrame

Tags: java, jframe, rectangles, ellipse

I have a simple question for you.
but I don't get why this does not draw rectangle and ellipse on JFrame.
I got JFrame windows so far but there is only grey background.

Please Explain Thank you.

FrameViewer.java

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class FrameViewer {
    JFrame frame;
    public void createFrame()
    {
        frame = new JFrame("CLOCK");
        frame.setSize(600, 600);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //add box and ellipse on the Frame
        ClockComponent component = new ClockComponent();
        frame.add(component);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

ClockComponent.java

```
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D.Double;
import javax.swing.JComponent;

public class ClockComponent extends JComponent{
    Rectangle square;
    Ellipse2D.Double ellipse;

    public void createComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        //create rectangle
        square = new Rectangle(100, 100, 100, 100);
        g2.draw(square);

        //create ellipse
        ellipse = new Ellipse2D.Double(5, 10, 100, 150);
        g2.draw(ellipse);
    }

}
```

AnalogClock.java

```
public class AnalogClock {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        FrameViewer clock = new FrameViewer();
        clock.createFrame();
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried the search-function from stackoverflow - there are **tons** of answers on this topic....

Comment: in the code provided, you never make a call to `createComponent` in the `ClockComponent` class

Comment: @CalvinP.  You are right. and I think because of my implementation of codes.

Comment: You'll want to take a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `ClockComponent` class, instead of the `createComponent(...)` method, add this:

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    //create rectangle
    square = new Rectangle(100, 100, 100, 100);
    g2.draw(square);

    //create ellipse
    ellipse = new Ellipse2D.Double(5, 10, 100, 150);
    g2.draw(ellipse);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Rather than extending to `JComponent` you can extend Class `ClockComponent` to `JApplet`

Then...

your `AnalogClock.Java` class has no problem

**ClockComponent.java** : can be extended to `JApplet` and `override` the `paint` function.

```
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import javax.swing.JApplet;


public class ClockComponent extends JApplet{
    Rectangle square;
    Ellipse2D.Double ellipse;


    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

        g2.setPaint(Color.BLACK);
        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(5.0f));// thickness of the line
        g2.draw(new Ellipse2D.Double(50, 50, 250, 250)); //(x point, y point, width, height)
    }
}
```

Then **FrameView.java** : file also should be edited as follows

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class FrameView {
    JFrame frame;
    public void createFrame()
    {
        frame = new JFrame("CLOCK");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


        JApplet applet = new ClockComponent();
        frame.getContentPane().add(applet);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

there are many ways to do this task, This is only one way to draw 2D

Hope this will help you!!

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining JApplet but I haven't learn that far yet but I will try this as practice.

Comment: Why? Why would you ever need to extend from JApplet to simply add it to a JFrame? Applets are suppose to be displayed in web pages, but since the plugin has been deprecated, there should never be a need to extending from JApplet ever again